# TFS 2017 - ProjectPath is NULL in DimTeamProject in TFS_Warehouse

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

We have recently upgraded to TFS 2017 from 2013 and all reports have migrated across fine. However, I have created a new Project under an existing collection but the reports are not built.

I noticed that in the TFS_Warehouse database the table DimTeamProject has a column called ProjectPath as empty.

I also noticed that there was no folder on the reporting services area which I am not surprised at based on the above. I have manually created this and added some of the template reports in there. When I run them they are empty but if I populate the ProjectPath field in the database which is empty then all is fine. Problem is, this is wiped away every night (must be a service running).

I have traced the field being populated from a procedure (prc_Dimension_DimTeamProject_AddUpdate) but the values come from an XML document located somewhere ( i have no idea where).

I have looked at the admin area on the server and the report path seems fine /TfsReports/{my}Collection

I can't see anything on the front end that indicated reports are set on or off.

1. I have rebuilt the 2 databases in TFS admin console. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/rebuild-data-warehouse-and-cube
2. Then I have manually processed the 2 databases by invoking the following webservice methods.

http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
ProcessWarehouse
ProcessAnalysisDatabase.

but when it comes to the manually processing I hit the following error.

```
<Job Name="Test Management Warehouse Sync" JobProcessingStatus="Idle">
<LastRun QueueTimeUtc="2017-02-09T09:12:10.663Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2017-02-09T09:12:10.707Z" EndTimeUtc="2017-02-09T09:12:11.927Z" Result="Failed">
<ResultMessage>
[Test Management Warehouse Sync]: ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: TF221122: An error occurred running job Test Management Warehouse Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server MYCollection. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean& more) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResult() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.WarehouseResultDatabase.ProcessResultDataSet(SqlDataReader reader, ProcessMappingDataCallback addedCallback, Mapping mapping, Boolean resolveIdentitesInBatch) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.WarehouseResultDatabase.QueryTestPointData(SqlBinary watermark, SqlBinary endWatermark, Int32 limit, IEnumerable`1 areaIterationMap, ProcessRowCallback deletedCallback, ProcessMappingDataCallback addedCallback, ResolveIdentities resolveIdentitiesCallBack) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.QueryForTestPoints(WarehouseResultDatabase wrd, SqlBinary waterMark, Int32 limit) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass116_0.<ProcessIntegratedResults>b__0() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.ProcessDataWithDiagnosticInfoLogging[T](Func`1 processBatch, Int32 limit, T& highWaterMark) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.MakeDataChanges() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.MakeDataChanges(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, String& resultMessage) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.RunInternal(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
</ResultMessage>
</LastRun>
<NextRun QueueTimeUtc="2017-02-09T09:31:55.777Z" JobState="QueuedScheduled"/>
</Job>
```

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

I have had the very same experience after upgrading to TFS 2017 RTM, and it turns out that the exception you are getting here about the "The datediff function resulted in an overflow.", is an issue in that particular version. I have written about that behavior, and what information you would need to prepare, prior reaching Microsoft, in order to get assistance here:
https://dankovalkov.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/tfs-2017-resolving-tf221122-tf246018-tf400307-and-tf400797-issues/